# Show pop-up when clicking on links in email contents

Tags: popup, html-email

I am facing a new requirement. My website has email sending facility, which contains links also. What I need is to show popup when I click on the link in the email contents, the contents may or may not be from the website. Which methods I can do for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to have a link to an external page that will open in a browser and execute the popup.

If the content is not from a website I can't see a way of doing this. It will require javascript which cannot be used in an email.